# Why ={} initialization doesn't work for tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, initializer-list, list-initialization

To me a `pair` is just special case of a `tuple`, but following surprises me:

```
pair<int, int> p1(1, 2);   // ok
tuple<int, int> t1(1, 2);  // ok

pair<int, int> p2={1, 2};  // ok
tuple<int, int> t2={1, 2}; // compile error
```

Why there is difference when we use `{}` to initialize `tuple`?

I tried even `g++ -std=c++1y` but still has error:

```
a.cc: In function 'int main()':
a.cc:9:29: error: converting to 'std::tuple<int, int>' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'constexpr std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple(_U1&&, _U2&&) [with _U1 = int; _U2 = int; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = int]'
     tuple<int, int> t2={1, 2};
                             ^
```

Comment: You should be able to do `auto t2=tuple<int, int>{1, 2};` if you want the copy initialization syntax. Re the error, the error message says it all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`tuple` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) you're trying to call is `explicit`, so [*copy-list-initialization* will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13461382/241631). The corresponding [`pair` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) is not `explicit`.

Change your code to

```
tuple<int, int> t2{1, 2};
```

and it'll compile.

Comment: Is there any reason that `tuple` uses explicit constructor?

Comment: @Deqing If it didn't, then a `tuple` containing a single type could be implicitly constructed from a value that is convertible to that type.

Comment: @Praetorian To avoid that, perhaps tuple could have had explicit constructor taking one argument, and non-explicit constructor taking two or more?

Comment: @MattMcNabb See Howard's answer, looks like this has been fixed in a different manner

Answer (score 31):

In addition to [Praetorian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241631/praetorian) [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084746/576911) (which I've upvoted), I wanted to add a little more information...

Post-C++14, the standard has been changed to allow:

```
tuple<int, int> t2={1, 2};
```

to compile and have the expected semantics.  The proposal that does this is [N4387](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html).  This will also allow constructs such as:

```
tuple<int, int>
foo()
{
    return {1, 2};
}
```

It only allows it if all `T` in the `tuple` are implicitly contructible from all arguments.

As a non-conforming extension, libc++ already implements this behavior.

Comment: You say "non-conforming": does this extension change the behaviour of any code which is correct under C++14?

Comment: @MattMcNabb:  Yes.  `is_convertible<int, std::tuple<int>>{}` is false in C++14 and true in C++1z.  The powers of C++ introspection have gotten so strong that it is nearly impossible to write conforming extensions these days.

Comment: If anyone has the rep for a 1-character edit, there's now an https version of that N4387 link.