# Could not convert from brace-enclosed initializer list to std tuple

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

As part of a bigger project, I'm playing with `std::tuple` and templates; consider the following code:

```cpp
template <typename ...T> void foo(tuple<T...> t) {}
void bar(tuple<int, char> t) {}
tuple<int, char> quxx() { return {1, 'S'}; }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    foo({1, 'S'});           // error
    foo(make_tuple(1, 'S')); // ok
    bar({1, 'S'});           // ok
    quxx();                  // ok
    return 0;
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084829) C++17 supports tuple initialization from *copy-list-initialization*, however it seems such support is limited since I get the following error (GCC 7.2.0):

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
main.cpp:14:17: error: could not convert '{1, 'S'}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::tuple<>'
     foo({1, 'S'}); // error
                 ^
```

Is there any way I can use brace-enclosed syntax in this scenario?

**Some Context** : this is going to be used in an operator overload so I guess I'm bound to tuples and cannot make use of variadics, any hint is well-accepted.

**Extra** : Clang 6 also complains

```
prog.cc:12:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo({1, 'S'});           // error
    ^~~
prog.cc:6:31: note: candidate function [with T = <>] not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'tuple<>'
template <typename ...T> void foo(tuple<T...> t) {}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *braced-init-list*, like `{1, 'S'}`, does not actually have a type. In the context of template deduction, you can only use them in certain cases - when deducing against `initializer_list<T>` (where `T` is a function template parameter) or when the corresponding parameter is already deduced by something else. In this case, neither of those two things is true - so the compiler cannot figure out what `...T` is supposed to be.

So you can provide the types directly:

```
foo<int, char>({1, 'S'});
```

Or you can construct the `tuple` yourself and pass that in:

```
foo(std::tuple<int, char>(1, 'S')); // most explicit
foo(std::tuple(1, 'S')); // via class template argument deduction
```

---

Today, `ClassTemplate<Ts...>` can only be deduced from expressions of type `ClassTemplate<Us...>` or types that inherit from something like that. A hypothetical proposal could extend that to additionally try to perform class template argument deduction on the expression to see if that deduction succeeds. In this case, `{1, 'S'}` isn't a `tuple<Ts...>` but `tuple __var{1, 'S'}` does successfully deduce `tuple<int, char>` so that would work. Such a proposal would also have to address issues like... what if we're deducing `ClassTemplate<T, Ts...>` or any minor variation, which isn't something that class template argument deduction allows (but is something that many people have at times expressed interest in being able to do).

I'm not aware of such a proposal today.

Comment: Can we hypothesize this will change? Is there any proposal about this, maybe for C++2a?

Comment: @SamuelePilleri No, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

> According to this answer C++17 supports tuple initialization from copy-list-initialization, however it seems such support is limited since I get the following error

The problem is another.

When you call `bar({1, 'S'})`, the compiler knows that `bar()` receive a `tuple<int, char>`, so take `1` as `int` and `'S'` as `char`.

See another example: if you define

```
void baz (std::tuple<int> const &)
 { }
```

you can call

```
baz(1);
```

because the compiler knows that `baz()` receive a `std::tuple<int>` so take `1` to initialize the `int` in the tuple.

But with

```
template <typename ...T>
void foo(tuple<T...> t)
 { }
```

the compiler doesn't know the `T...` types; when you call

```
foo({1, 'S'});
```

what `T...` types should deduce the compiler?

I see, at least, two hypothesis: `T = int, char` or `T = std::pair<int, char>`; or also `T = std::tuple<int, char>`.

Which hypothesis should follows the compiler?

I mean: if you pass a `std::tuple` to `foo()`, the compiler accept the list of types in the tuple as the list of `T...`; but if you pass something else, the compiler must deduce the correct `std::tuple`; but this deduction, in this case, is not unique. So the error.

Comment: That's what tricked me! I mean, `foo` expects a `std::tuple`, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @SamuelePilleri - And if you pass a `std::tuple`, it works; but if you pass something else, the compiler must deduce the correct tuple; but this deduction, in this case, is not unique. So the error.

Comment: Couldn't it use the same rules as class template argument deduction?

Comment: @SamuelePilleri - I don't know; I suppose will be some problems; anyway, from `std::tuple t({1, 'S'})`, which `std::tuple` should be deduced? `std::tuple<std::pair<int, char>>`? Or `std::tuple<std::tuple<int, char>>`? Remain the problem that from `{1, 'S'}` you can't deduce a unique type.

Comment: @max66 Presumably if we had this rule, we wouldn't arbitrarily insert parentheses?

Comment: @max66 Totally agree, but since both `tuple x(1, 'S')` and `tuple x{1, 'S'}` work I was wondering "why not?". Anyway, thank you both for your clarifications.

Comment: @Barry - do you mean that something as `foo({1, {'S', 2L}})` could add a recursive ambiguity?

Comment: @max66 I don't know why "ambiguity" - the only way that could possibly work is if we just decided that braced-init-lists were `tuple`s.

Comment: @Barry - so from `{1, {'S', 2L}}` we could deduce `std::tuple<int, std::tuple<char, long>>`? Anyway, I suppose it could be possible: given that the target is `std::tuple<Ts...>`, initializing with `{as...}` we could give a preferred deduction for `std::tuple<decltype(as)...>`; and if we want `std::tuple<std::pair<int, char>>` we could explicit with `foo<std::pair<int, char>>({1, 'S'})` or with `foo(std::make_pair(1, 'S'))`. But there isn't a risk that introducing this rule some old code change behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep bringing up `pair`, it is not relevant here. While it *may* be reasonable to allow deduction of `tuple<T...>` from `{1,'S'}`, you at least have `tuple` there to guide your deduction. How would you determine that the inner braced-init-list needed to *also* be a `tuple`? You have nothing to guide you there at all. I don't see how just assuming that we repeat the outer class template is reasonable.