# c++ add data to a std::vector containing a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, tuples

Below is code that adds elements to a vector containing a `std::pair`

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>> args_;

template <class T>
            inline OperationEntry& setArg(const std::string& name)
            {
                args_.push_back({name, typeid(T)});
                return *this;

            }
```

How do I add elements to a vector containing a `std::tuple`?

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Attribute>> args_;

template <class T>
            inline OperationEntry& setArg(const std::string& name, Attribute value = Attribute())
            {
                args_.push_back({name, typeid(T), value});
                return *this;

            }
```

I tried `args_.push_back(std::make_tuple(name, typeid(T), value));`

I am getting this error:

```
[GCC] converting to
‘std::vector<std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::type_index,
mv::Attribute> >::value_type {aka
std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >, std::type_index, mv::Attribute>}’ from
initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple<
<template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements =
{const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >&, const std::type_info&, mv::Attribute&};
<template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Elements =
{std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >, std::type_index, mv::Attribute}]’
```

Comment: That is not the full error message.

Comment: [WFM](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b443d5e5ee2f7889) though I did have to remove `Attribute` (because I have no idea what it is) so maybe that's why. As ever, please present your [MCVE]. This is not optional.

Comment: See also [Why ={} initialization doesn't work for tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084706/why-initialization-doesnt-work-for-tuple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
args_.push_back({name, typeid(T), value});
```

Before [N4387](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387), `std::tuple`'s constructor used for the above initialization was unconditionally `explicit`, and if selected by overload resolution in a copy-list-initialization, the compiler was allowed to raise an error.

---

```
args_.push_back(std::make_tuple(name, typeid(T), value));
```

The above call will try to use a copy-constructor for an `std::type_info` instance which is non-copyable.

---

In order to construct a tuple in a pre-N4387 implementation, use `emplace_back`:

```
args_.emplace_back(name, typeid(T), value);
```

or push back a tuple of copy-constructible types:

```
args_.push_back(std::make_tuple(name, std::type_index{typeid(T)}, value));
//                                         ~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: N4387 is implemented in GCC 6.1: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html