# Why no constructors are called?

Tags: c++, constructor, move-constructor, temporary-objects

Here C() is a temporary object which should have been created with no-arg constructor and then I expected a call to move constructor. Yet none of them happened. Can someone exmplain why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class C{
    public:
        C(){std::cout<<"No arg\n";}
        C(const C& r){std:cout<<"Copy Cons\n";}
        C(C&& r){std:cout<<"Move Cons\n";}
};

int main() {
    C c(C());
}
```

Comment: @Nicol It's the most vexing parse actually. The OP's expectation is still wrong, but they would reasonably expect the default ctor once at least.

Comment: Close reason is wrong (or only partially wrong). This is most vexing parse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parse

Comment: No need to reopen, I edited the list with the right target.

Comment: I think this one is worth answering: `C c(C());` needs some analysis.

Comment: @Bathsheba Is there something that's missing from the dupe target you think?

Comment: @cigien: It took me well into a minute to figure this one out.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's fair, but the dupe target covers what you have in your answer, right?

Comment: Only difference in dup that it is not the same type, but I doubt that difference is significant

Answer (score 3):

The statement `C c(C());` is actually a function declaration for a function called `c` that returns `C` and takes a function (unnamed) as a parameter that returns a `C` and takes no parameters.

In other words, it's purely declarative and has no effect on the program.

This is an example of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Even if it we fixed that (with `C c((C()))` or `C c{C()}`) , pre-C++17 most compilers used permission granted by the language to optimise away that "extra" temporary object (and since C++17 [they *must* do so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60811795/4386278)), so at best you'd probably only see the output from a single default constructor invocation.

Comment: We call them _declarations_ in C++, not prototypes (which are subtly different things)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: It's a wiki answer - let's all edit it.

Comment: I'd rather harass you in comments :P

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings How about swords or duelling pistols?

Comment: Sure, that can work!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I'm a pretty good shooter, but my swordsmanship is wanting.

Comment: Swords it is then.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Damn. My weakness is to reveal my weakness. Costly.

Comment: You walked right into that one...

Comment: I see that you've added an answer that says what would happen if the OP's code didn't suffer from MVP. It seems that you could post the answer on the dupe target as well. May I ask you to do that instead, so as not to have good quality answers to the same question spread out across the site?

Comment: @cigien No, because the "dupe target" doesn't mention, not even once, an expectation of a move ctor or copy ctor being invoked. So, the explanation you're referring to has nothing at all to do with that other question. That's why _this is not a duplicate_. Can we just relax and be happy that this OP got a nice, complete answer to their question? There are more important things to worry about.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ignore my previous comment, I wasn't thinking about this correctly. I see now that your answer clarifies the misunderstanding the OP has, and is useful in that regard at least, even though the underlying cause is covered in the dupe target. Thanks for taking the effort to write out an answer.