# Can "T t = {};" and "T t{};" produce different results?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

The question is simple. Is it possible to construct such a type T, for which the following two variables declarations will produce different results?

```
T t1 = {};
T t2{};
```

I've been digging through the cppreference and the standard for more than an hour now, and I understood the following:

- `T t2{};` is a [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). No surprises here.
- `T t1 = {}` is a [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) with an empty braced-init-list.

But the last one is tricky since the "effects of list initialization" is an impressive... list. Which for classes, fundamental types and aggregates seems to boil down to value initialization. But I am not sure I haven't missed anything.

Maybe you can provide a context, in which the two declarations will have different effects?

**UPD:** Excellent answers about `explicit` constructors! Next level: is it possible that both statements compile, but have different effects on compile/run time?

Comment: Re: UPD. Now you're just being difficult!  I have found a case where both *fail* to compile (but for different reasons), but working on one where they both compile but give different results. Tricksy.

Comment: I can do it by changing your first case to this: `T t1 = std::initializer_list<int>{};`. Would you consider that, or am I cheating?

Comment: `T t1 = std::initializer_list<int>{};` is definitely a cheating, since I am interested in the exact forms I've provided.

Comment: "I have found a case where both fail to compile (but for different reasons)" - That's also interesting! Can you please share it?

Comment: On a related note, turns out assignment `T t; t = {};` can behave differently from `t = T{};` if its `operator=` has an `initializer_list` overload. E.g. if you assign `{}` to a container of non-copyable (possibly movable) elements, you get an error (compiler wants to have a copy ctor to copy 0 elements from the init list), while `= T{}` does work.

Comment: @Mikhail Actually, I was wrong -  I *can* make both fail, but they fail with the *same* error message. Sorry.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, `T t1;  t1 = {};` calls an assignment function, but the original `T t1 = {}` is ***not*** an assignment, so any defined `=` operator isn't called, or even considered. Tried that one.

Comment: @AdrianMole I kind of expected `T t1 = {}` to prefer an `initializer_list` contructor, but nope.

Comment: It's a good 'un, to be sure! As soon as you put a value inside the braces then it become readily doable. The problem is in getting the compiler to see the `{}` explicitly as an (empty) initializer list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the standard differentiate between direct-list-initialization and copy-list-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461027/why-does-the-standard-differentiate-between-direct-list-initialization-and-copy)

Comment: Note, I did a [twitter quiz on a similar case recently w/ bool and nullptr](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1259674908553928708)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you consider a case in which one statement *will* compile, but the other will *not* compile as "different effects," then yes, here's a context:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class T {
public:
    int data{ 0 };
    explicit T() {
        data = 0;
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    T t1 = {};
    T t2{};
    return 0;
}
```

The line declaring/initializing `t1` gives the following, with `clang-cl`:

> error : chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization

The `MSVC` compiler also complains:

> error C2512: 'T': no appropriate default constructor available 
>   message : Constructor for class 'T' is declared 'explicit'

Comment: Great, thanks! What about if I want both statements to compile? :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in `explicit`. I've managed to make msvc difference, but it looks like a compiler bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct T
{
    template<class... A>
    T(A...) {std::cout << "1\n";}
    explicit T() { std::cout << "2\n"; }

};


int main()
{
    T t1 = {}; // 1
    T t2{}; // 2
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! What about if I want both statements to compile? :)

Comment: Yeah, looks like a compiler bug.